# Problema ao enviar arrays de um método para outro utilizando Thread em Java

Tags: java, array, thread, redes, concorrência

Estou fazendo um programa que simula o envio de uma mensagem da camada física para outra camada física do modelo OSI (referência da ISO) de redes. Meu código possui um método que envia "quadros" separadamente. Esses quadros são divididos por espaços, e são arrays de inteiros que possuem códigos ASCII de um conjunto de letras. Contudo, ao enviar esses "quadros" para o método utilizando uma Thread, **eles são enviados de forma diferente a cada execução**. Exemplo: envio "ab cde", é recebido "ab", ou "cde", algumas vezes "cdeab" e, raramente "ab cde". O que a Thread está fazendo com o envio do método?

Obs.: Decidi disponibilizar o projeto no GitHub.  https://github.com/Hugorc10/Camada_Fisica_Redes.git

```
private void enviarQuadros(int[] quadroEnquadrado) {
        System.out.print("\nEnviar Quadros\n");
        switch (this.tipoDeEnquadramento) {
            case 0:
                int x = 0;
                int[] quadro;
                int index = 0;
                while (x < quadroEnquadrado.length) {
                    int cont = 0;
                    index = quadroEnquadrado[x];
                    quadro = new int[index];
                    quadro[cont] = index;
                    cont++;
                    x++;

                    for (int y = 0; y < index - 1; y++) {
                        quadro[cont] = quadroEnquadrado[x];
                        cont++;
                        x++;
                    }

                    int[] finalQuadro = quadro;
                    Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            camadaFisicaTransmissora(finalQuadro);
                        }
                    });

                    thread.start();
                }
                break;
        }
    }

    private void camadaFisicaTransmissora(int[] quadro) {
        System.out.print("\nCamada Fisica Transmissora\n");
        camadaFisica.clear = false; // Impede de limpar a tela
        int[] fluxoBrutoDeBits = new int[0];

        if (binarioRadioButton.isSelected()) {
            try {
                camadaFisica.revalidate();
                camadaFisica.repaint();

                limparTela();
                camadaFisica.clear = false;

                fluxoBrutoDeBits = camadaFisicaTransmissoraCodificacaoBinaria(quadro);

                camadaFisica.bits = new String[fluxoBrutoDeBits.length];
                for (int i = 0; i < fluxoBrutoDeBits.length; i++)
                    camadaFisica.bits[i] = Integer.toBinaryString(fluxoBrutoDeBits[i]);

                camadaFisica.setEncodingTechnique(camadaFisica.BINARIO);

                for (String s : camadaFisica.bits)
                    bitsReceptor.append(s);

                System.out.print("Imprimindo bits receptor: " + Arrays.toString(camadaFisica.bits) + "\n");
            } catch (NumberFormatException e1) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Entrada Invalida", "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            } catch (Exception e1) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Excecao Desconhecida Ocorreu", "Exception", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            }
        }

        meioDeComunicacao(fluxoBrutoDeBits);
    }

    public static int[] camadaFisicaTransmissoraCodificacaoBinaria(int[] quadro) {
        System.out.print("\nCamada Fisica Transmissora Codificacao Binaria\n");

        // Variavel que ira receber o comprimento (length) do array "quadro" dividido por quatro
        int n = quadro.length / 4;

        // Verifica  se o comprimento do quadro divido por quatro tem resto diferente de 0
        if (quadro.length % 4 != 0)
            n++;

        int[] bits = new int[n]; // Array que ira conter os inteiros com os bits armazenados no array "quadro"

        int index = 0;

        // Realiza loop ate o i ser menor que o comprimento (length) do vetor bits
        for (int i = 0; i < bits.length; i++) {
            bits[i] = quadro[index];
            index++;

            for (int y = 0; y < 3; y++) {
                if (index < quadro.length) {
                    bits[i] = bits[i] << 8; // Desloca 8 bits a esquerda
                    bits[i] = bits[i] | quadro[index]; // Compara os bits do array 'quadro' para o array 'bits'
                    index++;
                } // fim do if
            } // fim do for
        } // Fim do for

        System.out.print("Imprimindo bits: " + Arrays.toString(bits) + "\n");

        return bits;
    } // Fim do metodo camadaFisicaTransmissoraCodificacaoBinaria
```

Esta é uma imagem do programa que estou implementando com a mensagem recebida.

[image: Esta é uma imagem do programa que estou implementando com a mensagem recebida.]

Comment: Ajudaria muito se poder fornecer um **[mcve]** pois assim seria possivel testar seu codigo e ver o problema acontecendo.

Comment: Decidi disponibilizar o projeto no GitHub. HTTPS: https://github.com/Hugorc10/RedesDeComputadores.git

Answer (score 0):

Dependendo do paramentro `int[] quadroEnquadrado` podem ser lançadas varias Threads, mesmo que todas as threads façam exatamente a mesma coisa, nada garante que acabem pela mesma ordem que começaram, nessa situação, um thread pode ter mais que fazer que as outras, assim acaba mais tarde, tocando assim a ordem de "ab cde" para "cdeab".
Nas situações em que recebes "ab" ou "cde" é possivel que a ultima thread a terminar substitua o que as restantes threads fizeram.

Susgestão:

- juntar tudo num `int[]` e enviar
- Usar mecanismos de sincronização como Mutex ou Semaphore (Encontrei este artigo que o pode ajudar: https://www.mkyong.com/java/java-thread-mutex-and-semaphore-example/)